# encodings.CodecRegistryError while using pycharm's remote debugger

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, encode

When I used Pycharm's remote debugger to run or debug my program on my server(linux, python2.7), I got an error as follow:
encodings.CodecRegistryError: incompatible codecs in module "encodings.utf_8" (/usr/local/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc).
But I can run it successfully on my server using its command line without pycharm remote debugger.

I think maybe I need to modify the config of my server, but how to do that?

Comment: I finally solved it by re-installing the python on server.